# Parsing JSON in windows command line with curl

Tags: json, curl

I'm trying to do JSON parsing the command line using Curl.
I have a query where many parameters, I have to put in a variable digit field name.
url-localhost:15672/api/queues

Comment: try installing python. And use some `simplejson` sort of thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you have neglected to ask a question. You can [edit] to clarify, but also be clear about how this is a programming question. Curl is a standalone program, and as far as I know, it doesn't do parsing, so why have you chosen it as your parsing tool instead of the scores of other options?

Comment: I just need to have a batch file without python